# Library for Dom Generation Using JS Functions

Tags: html, dom, javascript

I'm looking for a library that would allow me to generate DOM using simple js functions.

Here's an example of how I would imagine the code might look like:

```
var dom = 
    div({class:'aaa', style:'background-color: yellow;'}, [
        h1([text('Hello')]),
        h2([text('World')])
    ])

$('body').innerHTML(dom.render())
```

Have you seen anything of this sort?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the world of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)!

Comment: It's not a bad question. There are a lot of libraries that do exactly what he asks. See https://github.com/fgnass/mkay. "Why?" it asks. "Because building DOM fragments with plain jQuery is slow and noisy."

Comment: While it's certainly an interesting question, it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow. See [Why are library recommendation questions prohibited?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134914/142802).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's not bad:

```
var dom = $('<div class="aaa"/>')
    .css('background-color', 'yellow')
    .append(
        $('<h1/>').text('Hello'),
        $('<h2/>').text('World')
    );
```

Try Googling "js dom builder". I found:

- http://insin.github.io/DOMBuilder/build.html
- https://code.google.com/p/mkup/wiki/Examples.
- https://github.com/fgnass/mkay

Comment: Thanks. jquery requires way too many characters to define a simple dom (just compare your example to jade or haml). But the links are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)!

```
var div = $("<div>")
              .addClass("aaa")
              .css({background: "yellow"})
              .append("<h1>Hello</h1>")
              .append("<h2>World</h2>")
              .appendTo("body");
```